# 3D rotation defining the intersection of 2 planes

Tags: trigonometry, vectors, 3d, rotations, angle

> [image: 3 triangles ΔDCE, ΔDAE and ΔDBE]

Triangles $DAE$, $DCE$ and $DBE$ form a quadrangle $ABCD$, where $\angle BAD$ and $\angle BCD$ are right angles.

I have a scenario in which I want to find the angles $\angle ABD$ and $\angle DBE$, which form the rotation of BE from BA, in terms of $\angle ABC$, $\angle DCE$, $\angle DAE$ and $DB$. I got as far as

$$\angle DBE = \tan^{-1} \frac{DA \tan (\angle DAE)} {DB}$$

but am unsure about how to define $DA$ in terms of $\angle ABC$, $\angle DCE$, $\angle DAE$ and/or $DB$. Or maybe this is unsolvable for the terms that I want?

I stumbled upon the [Rodrigues' rotation formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodrigues%27_rotation_formula) and while it sounds like it might be the way to go about this, the breakdown of it completely lost me.

This is all to be used in a script to rotate an extruded shape that has been multiplied through a corner.

**Following** from Cosmas Zachos, $$\angle ABD = tan^{-1}(\frac{tan(\angle ABC)sin(\angle ABC)tan(\angle DCE)} {sin(\angle ABC)tan(\angle DCE)+tan(\angle DAE)tan(\angle ABC)})$$

<s>where $\angle ABC \ne 90$ ?</s>

$$\Longrightarrow\angle DBE = tan^{-1}(\frac {BDsin(\angle ABD)tan(\angle DAE)}{BD})$$

Comment: What are you thinking of rotating?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your proposed rotation is quite misconceived, when plain Alexandrian trigonometry will work. You started out right.

Try to determine $\theta \equiv \angle ABD$ first, through $\triangle ABD$ , then $\triangle ADE$; but also $\triangle BCD$, then $\triangle CDE$, both depending on it differently,
$$
DA=DB \sin \theta \Longrightarrow DE= DA \tan ( \angle DAE ) = DB   \tan ( \angle DAE )  \sin\theta \\
CD=DB \sin(\angle ABC-\theta)  \Longrightarrow DE=CD \tan(\angle DCE)=DB  \tan(\angle DCE) \sin (\angle ABC-\theta).
$$

Equating *DE* from each alternate path,
$$
\tan(\angle DCE)\sin (\angle ABC-\theta)= \tan (\angle DAE) \sin \theta \qquad \Longrightarrow \\
\cot \theta= \cot (\angle ABC) + \frac{\tan (\angle DAE)}{\sin (\angle ABC)\tan (\angle DCE) } ~~.
$$

Your other unknown angle follows then from
$$
\tan (\angle DBE)=DE/DB= \tan (\angle   DAE) \sin\theta =  \tan (\angle   DAE) \frac{1} {\sqrt{1+\cot^2\theta}} ~.
$$